# cross domain popup window.

Tags: javascript, html, popup, cross-domain

I have two different domains like,

- www.websiteone.com
- www.websitetwo.com

**So what i want to do is,**

1) when user is on `www.websiteone/page.php.com` and clink a `link`, i want to showing a popup window which contains Register information. The popup page should be a, `.aspx` or `html` and its need to be hosted in `www.websitetwo.com/Register.aspx`. Is it doable?

Please let me know your suggestion...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *Register information*?

Comment: cant you just use window.open() ?

Comment: Register details like Name, Email,Phone,..etc

Comment: @Techmonk: Can you pls give me any samples or link..

Answer (score 0):

```
var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,titlebar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=600";


    var myWindow=window.open('www.websitetwo.com/Register.aspx','_blank',strWindowFeatures);
myWindow.focus();
```

for documentation http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp